# nsinternalinconsistencyexception could not load nib in bundle xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a solution with a Xamarin.Ios library containing views and nibfiles. Furthermore the solution have a iphone app project(duh) with a reference to the library.
Earlier when compiled and executed the nibfiles where copied correctly into the application. If I found the app in the simulator and pushed show contents the nibfiles would be there.

However after updating to the newest 8.6 from xamarin the nibfiles are no longer copied, which results in the lovely nsinternalinconsistencyexception could not load nib in bundle error. The nibfiles are set as interfacedefinition and copy are set to "do not copy".

Do anyone have a suggestion to where to look?

Any help is highly appreciated

Update:

I added the fix as mentioned in the answer at it fixed  half of my issue however for now i need to link view files from my library for them to be included in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know issue (been reported in Xamarin's bugzilla system). In XI 8.6.0 there are some conditions where the new, `msbuild`-based, build *forgets* to copy some files in the application bundle.

A workaround (or most cases) is to edit a `.target` file like described [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25569#c3).

The upcoming service release (8.6.1) is fixing this issue.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. if it works your my hero :p

Comment: It seems that it fixes my issue with missing icons but not the nib files

Comment: It's not the only fix coming up, but to be 100% sure it would be helpful if you can file a bug report (bugzilla.xamarin.com) with a test case. We'll be able to confirm it's part of the service release or (if it's not) make sure it gets fixed asap.

Comment: I will make a solution later today and file the bug

Comment: If I create a new project with a ios app and library it works as intended. Maybe the migration assistant in xamarin studio removed som project settings

Comment: Hard to say, I have not heard of such a bug. If you can make a `diff` between the old and new .csproj files and file a bug report then someone can have a look at it.  Make sure to include specific (incl. XS) version numbers.